# Can't access Mesos UI

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

Can't access Mesos UI on the master:5050.

Running a small cluster 1 master-3 slaves on a Linux dist.

Master seems to be picked OK:

```
I0902 09:43:23.234127 19479 zookeeper.cpp:262] A new leading master (UPID=master@X:5000) is detected
I0902 09:43:23.234194 19479 master.cpp:2170] Elected as the leading master!
```

The connection master-slaves seems to be OK, logs from the master:

```
I0902 09:43:23.391279 19478 hierarchical.cpp:854] Added agent 70773e6b-80f2-45ce-945e-2fdbc8202b35-S113 (XXXXXX) with cpus:2; mem:2872; disk:4089; ports:[31000-32000] (allocated: {})
I0902 09:43:24.101581 19480 hierarchical.cpp:854] Added agent 70773e6b-80f2-45ce-945e-2fdbc8202b35-S111 (XXXXXXX) with cpus:2; mem:2872; disk:4089; ports:[31000-32000] (allocated: {})
I0902 09:43:24.114173 19479 hierarchical.cpp:854] Added agent 70773e6b-80f2-45ce-945e-2fdbc8202b35-S112 (XXXXXXXX) with cpus:2; mem:2872; disk:4089; ports:[31000-32000] (allocated: {})
```

In the master machine the port 5050 doesn't seem to be used at all, this line returns nothing:

```
sudo lsof -n -P | grep '5050'
```

Edit: As per request adding the command sudo lsof -n -P | grep '5050'

Replaced IPs for X and Z but returns plenty of results:

```
mesos-mas 22077                 root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077                 root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077                 root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077                 root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22095           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22095           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22095           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22095           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22096           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22096           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22096           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22096           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22097           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22097           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22097           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22097           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22098           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22098           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22098           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22098           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22099           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22099           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22099           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22099           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22100           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22100           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22100           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22100           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22101           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22101           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22101           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22101           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22102           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22102           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22102           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22102           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22103           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22103           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22103           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22103           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22104           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22104           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22104           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22104           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22105           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22105           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22105           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22105           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22106           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22106           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22106           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22106           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22107           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22107           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22107           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22107           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22108           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22108           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22108           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22108           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22109           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22109           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22109           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22109           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22110           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22110           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22110           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22110           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22111           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22111           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22111           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22111           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22112           root    8u     IPv4              76135       0t0        TCP X:5000 (LISTEN)
mesos-mas 22077 22112           root   27u     IPv4              77128       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:53074 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22112           root   29u     IPv4              76230       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:57994 (ESTABLISHED)
mesos-mas 22077 22112           root   31u     IPv4              76232       0t0        TCP X:5000->Z:44922 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Can you try port `5000`?

Comment: @janisz Done as requested, plenty of connectios are established

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command was being launched with the command --port=5000, a bit confused because apparently this is the port the slaves listes to according to this definition from [this page](https://mesos.readthedocs.io/en/0.21.1/configuration/):

```
 Port to listen on (master default: 5050 and slave default: 5051)
```

At no point is nothing from the webui mentioned.